# Paraphrase this sentence please

Tags: meaning

It made her fear some conspiratorial, punishing power had carried her back home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.SE mad libs!

It made her ___1___ some ___2___ had ___3___  ___4___.

1:

```
terrified 
trepidatious 
concerned 
worried
```

2:

```
dark cabal
foul winds of fate
international banking conspiracy
throng of 50 Shades Of Grey fans
```

3:

```
forced her
coerced her
inexorably dragged her
yanked her like a fly into the mouth of some hideous, misbegotten frog behemoth
```

4:

```
back from whence she came
down to the filth-ridden hovel her parents mockingly called "home"
to the town where she was infamously known as "bed wetting girl"
back to life, back to reality: back to the here and now
```

Answer (score 0):

Quickly parsing this, there's an implied "that" after "fear." I might venture that the two "hers" are referring to different people, as well. I don't know what the "it" is from this limited context.

Thus:

> It caused [thinking female] to worry that [other female] had been returned home by a vengeful, conspiring force.

Edit: Since they are one person.

> It caused [female] to worry a vengeful, conspiring force had forced her to return to her home.

Comment: The two hers belong to one person. and 'it', here refers to some dull sights she had already seen and some thoughts. I don't know how to connect 'it made her fear..' and 'had carried...'

Answer (score 0):

That made she be afraid that there were occult forces at work, dragging her back home, as a punishment.

(just an attempt: non native speaker  :-)  please, correct me where wrong! )